# Vuejs how to trigger external script event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my `vue`-app I want to include an external script from a shop, so that when I click on a product, the script gets fired and opens the overlay with the buying process...

I tried to to this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
            
          <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
           
           // then the code, the shop requires for its overlay to work
           <a href="#" data-fsc-action="Add,Checkout" data-fsc-item-path-value="PRODUCT ID SHOULD BE HERE">Buy now 99$</a>  
           // product id = {{product.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
 </template>
```

then I included the script tag which is also provided by the shop ( for security reasons I cannot provide all of it...)

```
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
       {
         id: "fsc-api",
         src: "https://d1f8f9xcsvx3ha.cloudfront.net/...",
         type: "text/javascript",
         "data-storefront": "...",
         "data-popup-closed": "...",
         async: true,
       },
     ],
   };
 },
}
```

but this triggers nothing and I don't know how to solve this

can someone help me out?

Comment: fastspring uses DOMContentLoaded, if `products` is slow then the elements won't be there before it fires, you need to use `@click="addProduct('PRODUCT ID SHOULD BE HERE')"` then pass item/id etc to `window.fastspring.builder.add(item);`, then add one for `window.fastspring.builder.viewCart();`.. or instead of placing the script in head, plop it on the dom on mounted with document.createElement('script') etc, also if its nuxt, grab products and render serverside so the data- attributes are in place before DOMContentLoaded. Unfortunately, there is no way to re-init fastspring as init not exposed

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ok, good to know! Do you know what the correct payload is in this case? I keep getting `[FastSpring API] (!) Error: Error received:  400 payload-invalid`

Comment: Don't know, you need to check the docs https://fastspring.com/docs/passing-sensitive-data-with-secure-requests